# i searched but all the questions lead to same strings or even only two strings to be separated ,but my requirement covers wider version

Tags: sql, string, picking

I have this in a single row with a particular line number, I have to pick up the 2nd `67503.55-` and `51810.60-` and discard everything else.

```
TOTALS:            228                     67503.55-      **67503.55**-     165420.27      217230.87-      **51810.60**-      119314.15-
```

I tried using `fn_split` but with no help.

Comment: `sql` is not enough! Please use the edit option to tag your question with the appropriate RDBMS (MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle... whatever...)

Answer (score 0):

If your database supports `SPLIT_TOKEN()`, you can try this:

```
WITH
input(s) AS (
SELECT 'TOTALS: 228 67503.55- 67503.55- 165420.27 217230.87- 51810.60- 119314.15-'
)
SELECT
  SPLIT_PART(s,' ',4) AS first_needed_token
, SPLIT_PART(s,' ',7) AS second_needed_token
FROM input;

first_needed_token|second_needed_token
67503.55-         |51810.60-
```

Otherwise, ask for `SPLIT_TOKEN()` in your RDBMS .

Answer (score 0):

thanks ,I tried something like this which does same as split_token ,its sql server that I use and it does not support that function :-

col1= SUBSTRING(Col,9,14) , col2= SUBSTRING(Col,27,14),col3= SUBSTRING(Col,40,14)